# Why define norm of linear map as $\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|=\|A\|$?

Tags: analysis, multivariable-calculus

I studied basic topology and abstract algebra(junior course) before studying multivariable analysis.

In abstract algebra, we saw $\mathbb R$-vector space $\mathfrak M(m, n)=\{A\mid A\text{ is }m\times n\text{ matrix over }\mathbb R\}$ as $\mathfrak L(\mathbb R^n, \mathbb R^m)=\{L:\mathbb R^n\to \mathbb R^m\mid L \text{ is }\mathbb R\text{-linear map}\}$ and subset(subring) of $\mathbb R^{mn}$.

Then, in this case, norm of $m\times n$ matrix $A$ would be $\|A\|=\sqrt{\sum_{1\le i, j\le n}a_{ij}^2}$, as element of Euclidean space.

But, in PMA, Rudin says norm of linear map $L$ as $\|L\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Lx\|$.

Why should it be defined like this? Is this because the matrix acts as an operator acting on Euclidean space, not as an element of a simple set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With this definition, we have $\|L\circ M\|\leqslant\|L\|\cdot\|M\|$, which is quite useful. For instance, it follows from this that we always have $\|L^n\|\leqslant\|L\|^n$. And it follows from this that, if a power series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n$ has radius of oncergence $\rho>0$, then, if $\|L\|<\rho$, the series $\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nL^n$ converges (since it converges absolutely).

Comment: Thank you for your answer! So, what is the motivation of the norm $\|A\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|Ax\|$? Is it just $\|A\circ B\|\le\|A|\cdot\|B\|$?

Comment: Not only that. For each linear map $L\colon\Bbb R^n\longrightarrow\Bbb R^m$, there is a number $K$ (actually, infinitely many of them) such that, for each $v\in\Bbb R^n$, $\|L(v)\|\leqslant K\|v\|$. And, with this choice of norm, $\|L\|$ is the smallest such number. So,  for each $v\in\Bbb R^n$, $\|L(v)\|\leqslant\|L\|\cdot\|v\|$ and, if $0\leqslant K<\|L\|$, then there is some $v\in\Bbb R^n$ such that $\|L(v)\|>K\cdot\|v\|$.